# Using DbParameter instead of SqlParameter with _context.Database.SqlQuery for stored proc execution

Tags: entity-framework, repository, sqlparameter

I am using Entity Framework 6.1 and GenericRepository. To execute stored procedure I am using SqlQuery method. Currently I am using SqlParameters but being a GenericRepository I don't want to use some specific class. I tried multiple options but how can I use DbParameter here. I tried to access providerName (System.Data.SqlClient) from dbcontext but that is also not available. Any direction would help. Please let me know incase you want me to provide more informaiton.

```
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAllFromStoredProcedure(string storedProcedureName, List<StoredProcedureParameter> parameters)
    {
        List<SqlParameter> sqlParameters = new List<SqlParameter>();

        foreach (StoredProcedureParameter parameter in parameters)
        {
            sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter(parameter.Name, parameter.Type) { Value = parameter.Value});
        }

        return _context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(storedProcedureName, sqlParameters.ToArray());
    }
```

calling as -

```
    clientRepository.GetAllFromStoredProcedure("GetClients", parameters).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did for this -

In my Domain project (that has the Context and Entities created using Code First From Database), I added a class StoredProcedureParameter -

```
public class StoredProcedureParameter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DbType Type { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public static object[] CreateParameters(List<StoredProcedureParameter> parameters)
    {
        List<SqlParameter> sqlParameters = new List<SqlParameter>();

        foreach (StoredProcedureParameter parameter in parameters)
        {
            sqlParameters.Add(new SqlParameter(parameter.Name, parameter.Type) { Value = parameter.Value });
        }

        return sqlParameters.ToArray();
    }
}
```

And then in my Repository project (that has the GenericRepository and UnitOfWork), I added a new method -

```
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAllFromStoredProcedure(string storedProcedureName, List<StoredProcedureParameter> parameters)
    {
        return _context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(storedProcedureName, StoredProcedureParameter.CreateParameters(parameters));
    }
```

Now when calling Repository->GetAllFromStoredProcedure method (from my Application project) I will create the parameter list from Domain->StoredProcedureParameter->CreateParameters method. This ensures the parameters passed are of the correct type, my GenericRepository remains generic and my Application project is also unaffected.